# Changing formulas to values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have this code that exports a worksheet to the desktop. I want to change the formulas to values but only in the exported file, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks.

```
Sub ExportWorksheets()

    Dim worksheet_list As Variant, worksheet_name As Variant
    Dim new_workbook As Workbook
    Dim saved_folder As String
    Dim File_name As String
    Dim New_File_Name As String
    
    worksheet_list = Array("Sheet_02")
    
    
    '// makes sure you close the path with a back slash \
    saved_folder = Environ("userprofile") & "\Desktop\"
    
    For Each worksheet_name In worksheet_list
    
        On Error Resume Next
        ' Opens a new Excel wokrobook
        Set new_workbook = Workbooks.Add
        
        File_name = ThisWorkbook.Name
        
        File_name_02 = Replace(File_name, ".xlsm", "")
        
        New_File_Name = worksheet_name & "_" & File_name_02 & ".xlsx"

        
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheet_name).Copy new_workbook.Worksheets(1)
        
        
        new_workbook.SaveAs saved_folder & New_File_Name, 51
        new_workbook.Close False
        
    Next worksheet_name
    
 
    MsgBox "Export completed. " & New_File_Name, vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Immediately after your `Copy` line, `new_workbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Value2=new_workbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Value2`
(assuming that the copied sheet becomes the 'new' first sheet in `new_workbook`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next updated code. You do not need to previously create a new workbook, and `.Value = .Value` does what you need:

```
Sub ExportWorksheets()
    Dim worksheet_list As Variant, worksheet_name As Variant
    Dim saved_folder As String, File_name As String, New_File_Name As String
    
    worksheet_list = Array("Sheet_02")
    
    '// makes sure you close the path with a back slash \
    saved_folder = Environ("userprofile") & "\Desktop\"
    
    For Each worksheet_name In worksheet_list
        File_name = ThisWorkbook.name
        File_name_02 = Replace(File_name, ".xlsm", "")
        New_File_Name = worksheet_name & "_" & File_name_02 & ".xlsx"

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheet_name).Copy 'it automatically create a new workbook with the content of the respective sheet
        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange
            .value2 = .value2 'value2 is faster and may be used since the range has the same format...
        End With
        
        ActiveWorkbook.saveas saved_folder & New_File_Name, 51
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next worksheet_name
    
    MsgBox "Export completed. " & New_File_Name, vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now it copies the values, but it creates two documents. One with the custom name on the desktop but with the empty sheet and one with the name "Book" with the values that were formulas before, without saving anywhere.

Comment: @Antor Cha Did you test the code **exactly** how it is? Without any (maybe small) contribution...? If so, please run the code line by line (alternatively pressing `F8`) and move the cursor over the variables seeing what they display... You maybe were too fast and copied the code immediately... Please, refresh this page and copy it as it is. I replaced (in less than one minute...) `new_workbook.Close`, as initially in your code, with `ActiveWorkbook.Close`.

Comment: @Antor Cha Can you send some feedback? Do you still  have problems in using the above code?

Comment: Thanks for the help! It did work with your second comment.

Comment: Is it wrong if I used it like this `.value = .value2`

Comment: @Waleed It depends on the specific format the array keeps. If it is `Date`, for instance, `Value2` will keep the `Long` number, as Excel uses. If doing the above equivalence, you should format the returned value as `Date`. `.value2` is faster than `.value` because it does not make any conversion. It takes the data as it is. But, if you do not understand this aspect, sometimes it may return something not exactly the same with what you wanted to copy... For myself, if **I know what data must be handled** I always use `.value2`. When not, if the data range to be copied is not big, I use `.value`.